# Sticky footer wrapper not expanding to correct height

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I have a problem getting my sticky footer to "stick" to the bottom of the page. I am using the method given [here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) I am using a wrapper and push just as the method says to but my wrapper div doesn't seem to have the correct height.

You can see the problem being displayed at [michael-nolan.com](http://michael-nolan.com)

Thank you for any and all help and please leave a comment if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

add this to your css stylesheet

Comment: Completely missed that. Thank you.